# Prove that $\sum_{i=0}^n \sqrt{i}$ is irrational.

Tags: irrational-numbers

Prove that $1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\dots+\sqrt{n}$ is irrational for every natural number $n\ge2$.

Comment: **Hint:** There is some largest prime number in the set $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$

Comment: Some reference paper: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.630.1024&rep=rep1&type=pdf